# Kindle Fire HD 7" runs very slowly after rooting

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I recently rooted my Kindle Fire HD and it now runs very slowly. It was mentioned in the rooting instructions I was following that this would happen during the rooting process. I am wondering if this is a permanent consequence of rooting or if it is fixable. If it is something I can fix could you tell me how.
Thanks for the help!

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Download [Root MANY ANDROID!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460) to your desktop. Extract to your desktop. This package includes updated adb daemons.
2. Download [Qemu automated root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1893838) to your desktop. Extract to your desktop. This package includes updated adb daemons.

> NOTE WINDOWS 7 USERS: You need to open a command prompt "as Administrator" when running the above utility batch files `RunMe.bat` and `RootQemu.bat` - otherwise Windows will respond with "Permission Denied".
>
> Root Step 1: Run `RunMe.bat` from *Root MANY ANDROID!*. Choose option 1 Run Normal Method and ignore errors. Pay attention, you will need to answer "Restore" a dialogue box on the Kindle. Click on Restore. When the program has completed, the Kindle will Reboot.
>
> Root Step 2: When the Kindle reboots it will react VERY slowly, this is normal - leave it alone. Immediatly proceed to Step 3.
>
> Root Step 3: Run `RootQemu.bat` from *Qemu automated root*. Follow the instructions Step-by-Step allowing Windows to re-detect the Kindle between reboots (about 2 minutes). Let this utility complete to the end.
>
> Root Step 4: Click on `Superuser.apk` under the Apps tab.

Comment: What steps did you follow?

Comment: When I rooted my *Motorola Milestone 2*, I afterwards also had lags and instabilities. For me it helped to do a *factory reset*. Keep in mind to make a god backup of your apps/data before, as a *factory reset* will wipe the device (not the sdcard, though). As you are rooted already, [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) will be very helpful :)

Comment: Does a factory reset unroot the device?

Comment: @connor No it doesn't. Rooting modifies partitions of the phone that are not object to factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

The process of rooting your tablet shouldn't affect the performance.  However, any apps that are installed when rooting can affect the performance.  SuperUser is a very common and popular app that is used when rooting and I have not seen any performance impact when installing SU on Motorola and Samsung devices (100+ devices).

Based on the junk that the first link tried to get me to download and how my virus detection (AVG) went off after extraction of the Zip, I'm guessing that there could be an app that was installed when rooting the tablet that could cause some performance delays (adware, monitoring app, etc.).  It's an extremely large download to for just rooting a tablet and the fact that it has 2+ threats to security programs it's not a good sign.

You can look at apps that are taking up system resources by enabling [Developer Options](https://wiki.curiouslearning.org/index.php/Enable_Developer_Options) and then looking at "Process Stats" under Settings->Developer Options->Process Stats.  This will show you what apps are taking up a lot of CPU Cycles.  If there is something you don't recognize and it's not a Google service, it could be something that was installed when rooting and soaking up resources, slowing your system.

The .bat file in the second download (Qemu) looks legitimate and there is nothing malicious in the batch file.

You can try uninstalling Superuser.apk from your device and installing it from another source.  This could resolve the sluggishness you tablet is experiencing.

Before doing anything else, I would recommend doing a complete backup of your entire tablet so you have a restore point if anything else goes wrong.  I use TWRP on the devices I manage and I've had excellent experience with it.  It appears they have a version for the Kindle Fire [XDA Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2271909).  If you already have a way to backup everything from the system level, use that before installing/uninstalling anything else.