# How to root Kindle Fire HD 8.9"

Tags: rooting, amazon-kindle-fire, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

I have purchased a Kindle Fire HD 2. Generation (2012) and wanted to root it. I followed the instructions from [Rooting a new Kindle Fire HD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/rooting-a-new-kindle-fire-hd-july-13) and and other instructions found via google.
When I run the `Bin4ry` version, the pad is really slow afterwards for some reason. I found [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36448/kindle-fire-hd-7-runs-very-slowly-after-rooting) thread here, but it's not really helpfull.

I also tried the Qemu version, but this also doesn't work. The only thing this resolves is that it runs at normal speed after it's done, but the device is not rooted.

So are there any tips on how to do this? I would like to get Google Playstore running, instead of being chained to Amazon. All information I find with google leads me back to the same solutions which don't work.

Comment: Please see [Rooting a new Kindle Fire HD](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/49248/16575), which covers the 7" and 8.9" variants.

Comment: I even linked to this post in my question, because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: what doesn't work? are you on OS version 8.4.3? Are you getting error messages when following the steps in the answer that @Izzy linked (and that you linked)?

Comment: It's not rooted, which is what doesn't work. I checked my version and found out it is 8.5.1, so it seems that these solutions don't work there. I found some rootkit, whcih I will try tomorrow, whcih hopefully can do it.

Answer (score 1):

My Kindle OS is 8.5.1 where the above solutions don't work (nor any other I found via google).

However, I found a thread on [xda developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2672150) which pointed to a file name `root_master.apk` and this one successfully rooted my device.

When using this apk, the process was partially in chinese (which I don't understand), but it worked. Not sure if this app is safe though, so use at your own risk.